# Natbib agsm - comma and ampersand

Tags: natbib, punctuation, harvard-style, ampersand

I am writing my dissertation and I must use a Harvard style bibliography.

I am using `natbib` and `agsm`. The problem I have is the following: if I want to cite a book that has only 2 authors either I do not get an & between the authors or I do not get a comma between the authors and the date.

I get (author1 and author2, year) if I use

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\citestyle{aysep{char}}
```

or (author1 & author2 year) if I use

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
```

What do I have to do to get (author1 & author2, year)? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please always show a [minimal but working example with Bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) instead of a code snippet only. This would help us to reproduce the problem and to test our own suggestions.

Comment: There are lots and lots of bibliography styles out there that generate harvard-style -- also known as authoryear-style -- citation call-outs. Why did you choose the `agsm` style? It's known to make some, shall we say, idiosyncratic design choices.

Comment: Incidentally, doesn't the instruction `\usepackage[style=authoryear]{natbib}` generate an error message. I'd write `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` instead. Similarly, does `\citestyle{aysep{char}}` work? Writing `\setcitestyle{aysep={char}}` is more likely to succeed...

Comment: @Schweinebacke next time I'll provide a MWEB

Comment: @Mico I was told to use agsm...for the next time I'll have to Harvard reference what would you advise me to use?

Comment: @AgneseSonego - As I have no knowledge of your future bibliographic formatting needs, I don't think it would be useful for me to make any specific recommendations. For submissions to journals, the choice of bibliography style is generally already made for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure where the problem is:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author={First, A. and Second, B.},
  title={Title},
  publisher={Publisher},
  year=2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\citestyle{aysep={,}}

\begin{document}

\citet{test}

\citep{test}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

I used the `filecontents*` environment just to make the example self-contained. Use your own file, instead.

[image]

If you want & between names (I hope not or that's an imposition by the publisher), do as follows

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{test,
  author={First, A. and Second, B.},
  title={Title},
  publisher={Publisher},
  year=2017,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\citestyle{aysep={,}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\harvardand}{\&}}

\begin{document}

\citet{test}

\citep{test}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why but yesterday every time I used aysep the program signaled 17 errors and no & showed up (unfortunately it is a requirement). Thank you so much for the tips. Now everything works.